# Textorientation jquerymobile button textinput

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a html5 form with jquerymobile. On some of the textinputs I want to add a Help-button. I therefore included a -element with data-role button to the -tag. It is nearly what I want, but the position of the button and the text is not so nice. Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="t0098">Others <a href="#info_split" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext">i</a></label>
  <input type="text" name="t0098" id="t0098" data-clear-btn="true" />
</div>
```

The result looks like this: [image: Screenshot]

I assumed to add some CSS-rules like `vertical-align: middle !IMPORTANT` to it the label, but it doesn't seemed tochange it.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think the problem is not the label, but the image inside. Try applying `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `a` inside the label.

Comment: Setting both, the `label` and the `a` to `vertical-align: middle;` worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jan you should post your comment as an answer since you nailed the problem. Even if it begun as a comment, so Kai can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As recommended by alkis, I post this as an answer.)

To align the text and image correctly, you have to apply `vertical-align: middle;` to the `a` inside the `label`.

And, as mentioned by Kai, applying `vertical-align: middle;` to the `label` as well, gives the final touch.